# How Can i Create a View or table out of two tables so that their rows are not merged?

Tags: sql-server

I have two views that i want tho merge them into one view so that their records are not merge into one record! i mean suppose I have these tables :

Table one(suppose this is a sell table were our customer sold something!)

```
  Date           Description           Fee       Number        Money           
12/2/2012        something             10$        20          200$
10/3/2012      somethingelse           20$        30          600$
```

Table Two (suppose this is the table where our customer got money!)

```
  Date           Description           Money           
02/8/2012        someinfo              5000$
12/1/2012         stuff                3100$
```

And the resulting Table or view would be(based on the descending order on date) :

```
  Date           Description           Fee       Number        Money  
02/8/2012        someinfo               0          0           5000$    
10/3/2012      somethingelse           20$        30           600$
12/2/2012        something             10$        20           200$
12/1/2012         stuff                 0          0           3100$
```

How can I achieve this form? These two tables are separate ,but each has a unique personal ID which represents the salesmen account. ( so basically this means that these information belong to one person only.and our customer wants a report that gives him this specific view only!)
I tried using UNION on these two tables , but the rows where merged!! 
If i use Joins there would only be a row where the two tables row are merged together .So I am stuck here and dont know what to do now .

Comment: UNION ALL will not force uniqueness so if a single row from each table would cause duplication in the view you will see the duplication where UNION would not.

Comment: Pick your poison, all answers are correct.

Comment: Is there any difference between UNION and UNION ALL? i used UNION and didnt get the expected result?!

Comment: Yes, I explained it in my first comment. `UNION` essentially adds a `DISTINCT` to your results set where `UNION ALL` does not. You can search any search engine known to man for "Difference between UNION and UNION ALL" and it will get you the technically explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need UNION ALL not just UNION.

```
select Date, Description, Fee, Number, Money
from table1
    UNION ALL
select Date, Description, 0 Fee, 0 Number, Money
from table2
order by Date
```

Comment: You missed the As keyword for Fee And Number

Comment: You don't need as.  It works without.  I personally think it's overkill.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do it.

```
CREATE VIEW new_view AS

SELECT * FROM table_one

UNION ALL

SELECT *, 0 as Fee, 0 as Number FROM table_two;
```

Comment: The `SELECT * FROM` at the top does nothing. Remove it and the parentheses so I can upvote. :)

Comment: You don't need the parentheses and honestly, I'm not sure if they would screw up the syntax. I don't think they would, but I'd remove them. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try somthing like

```
CREATE VIEW vMyView
AS
SELECT [Date], [Description], [Fee], [Number], [Money]
FROM v1
UNION ALL
SELECT [Date], [Description], 0 AS [Fee], 0 AS [Number], [Money]
FROM v2
```